# Integrating pinax-badges in django with a points system

Tags: python, django, pinax

I am having trouble getting pinax-badges to work in my project. I followed the minimal usage [example](https://github.com/pinax/pinax-badges/blob/master/docs/usage.md) provided by creating a badges.py file in my app:

```
#badges.py

from pinax.badges.base import Badge, BadgeAwarded
from pinax.badges.registry import badges


class PointsBadge(Badge):
    slug = "points"
    levels = [
      "Bronze",
      "Silver",
      "Gold",
     ]
    events = ["points_awarded",]
    multiple = False

    def award(self, **state):
        user = state["user"]
        points = user.get_profile().points
        if points > 10000:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=3)
        elif points > 7500:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=2)
        elif points > 5000:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=1)


badges.register(PointsBadge)
```

and a pretty bad points function that in my users model that calls a takes a parameter of amount and adds it to the points field in my user model.

```
#User Model
class User(AbstractUser):
    ....
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)

def award_points(self,amount):
    self.amount = amount
    self.points+=amount
    self.save()
```

Now the function i am calling in a signal that checks when a user logs in and awards them some points.Like so

```
#signal.py
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in,user_logged_out
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from pinax.badges.registry import badges


@receiver(user_logged_in)
def award(sender,request ,user, **kwargs):
    user = request.user.award_points(5000)
    badges.possibly_award_badge("points_awarded", user=user)
```

I registered the signal as well just to make sure. I am still not getting the desire result, which is, as soon as a user logs in and is awarded 5000 points which is enough for a level 1 badge as defined in the badges.py file.
Apart from the signal i am not sure there is a more efficient way to achieve this result unless of course someone recommends a different method all together.

Responses Appreciated.

Comment: found the problem. I messed up my signal function definition. What worked was, i just moved the signal to my user models and removed the request parameter and hooked it up the old way with ` user_logged_in.connect(award) `at the end like so. ` def award(sender, user, **kwargs):
    user = user.award_points(5000)
    badges.possibly_award_badge("points_awarded", user=user)

user_logged_in.connect(award)
`

Comment: the one above is only for the points, the badges don't seem to work and i am not really sure how the `**state` parameter works to get the user instance and its associated points.

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.

In **models.py**

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from pinax.badges.base import Badge, BadgeAwarded
from pinax.badges.registry import badges

class PointsBadge(Badge):
    slug = "points"
    levels = [
        "Bronze",
        "Silver",
        "Gold",
    ]
    events = [
        "points_awarded",
    ]
    multiple = False

    def award(self, **state):
        user = state["user"]
        points = user.profile.points
        if points > 500:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=3)
        elif points > 50:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=2)
        elif points > 5:
            return BadgeAwarded(level=1)

badges.register(PointsBadge)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
    )
    points = models.IntegerField (
        default = 0
    )

    def award_points (self, points):
        self.points += points
        self.save()
```

In **signals.py** I create `profile` when `user` created

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

And then within my `view`

```
    request.user.profile.award_points(p.points)
    badges.possibly_award_badge("points_awarded", user=request.user)
```

Comment: I only got the points working. The badges are still elusive. I will try it again and upvote if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Badges work with my approach which is why I put it as an answer